# when and why to have a HTTP server along with websphere application server?

Tags: websphere-7, ibmhttpserver

Applications deployed on Websphere application server can be accessed by the user through the HTTP URL and the context root for that particular application. then when and why people use a Apache / IBM HTTP server in between user and Websphere application server?

If HTTP server is used in between user and Websphere application server how the URL redirection happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefits to using IBM HTTP Server are primarily performance and security.  [This developerWorks answer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14260968) is the best I've seen in response to the same question.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should accept it by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

1. IBM HTTP Server (IHS) Plugin manages access to WAS defined contexts
2. IHS Plugin can manage loadbalancing over WAS servers
3. IHS manages A LOT better HTTP traffic
4. IHS can handle static content withdrawing load from WAS
5. IHS can handle RewriteRules, VirtualHosts, Authentication and much more!